# Render в Route (react-router-dom) не рендерит компонент

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Всем привет!
У меня есть компонент с рутами:

1. App:

```
return (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/offers/:id"
        render={(props) => {
          const offer = findActiveOffer(offers, props.match.params.id);
          
            return (
              <DetailedOffer
                {...props.match.params}
                offer = {findActiveOffer(offers, props.match.params.id)}
              />);
            }}
            />;
      <Route
        render={() => {
          return (
            <div>Not found</div>
          );
        }}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
```

2. Компонент, который имеет линк на страницы:

```
<Link to={`/offers/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
```

При клике на линк, адрес в адресной строке меняется на нужный (например `/offers/1`), но компонент DetailedOffer почему-то не отрисовывается, а отображается Not found. В чем может быть причина и что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала проверьте, работает ли такой код. Чтобы получить в DetailedOffer match.params.id оберните компоненту App в widthRouter  Пример: `export default withRouter(App)`
В компоненте DetailedOffer так же оборачиваем все в withRouter `export default withRouter(DetailedOffer)`

само собой импортируем withRouter через  `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

В компоненте DetailedOffer в props уже будет нужный id. Достать его можно так `props.match.params.id`

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`/offers/:id`} render={() => <DetailedOffer/>} />
      <Route path='*' exact={ true } render={() => <div>Not found</div> } />
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

Остальной Ваш код мне не понятен, но попробуйте начать с этого кода, потом если что дополните его сами

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Желательно решить задачу без использования withRouter, однако даже с ним к сожалению не заработало